# Generic Converter - Am I Using Generics Correctly?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am unsure if I am using generics correctly for a method that I am writing. I am using [responseBodyConverter()](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.html#responseBodyConverter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-) method from Retrofit. As of now, I have the following implementation:

```
    public static <T> Converter<ResponseBody, T> getConverter(){

    return sRetrofit.responseBodyConverter(ParameterizedType.class, new Annotation[0]);
}
```

My question is: Can I use `ParameterizedType.class` to satisfy the `Type` requirement for `responseBodyConverter()`? I thought that I could achieve this using `T` as my type parameter, but everything I tried didn't work: `T.class`, just passing `T`, etc.

What I ultimately want is to have a method that will provide me a converter for different types of classes that I've defined. I don't want to have to define multiple methods which basically do the same thing, only for different types of converters. I often struggle with generics in Java, so any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the signature of the `getConverter()` method fixed? If not, I'd recommend to add a parameter of type `Class` and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type-erasure, the type of `T` is lost at runtime. The caller must supply the `Class`, e.g.

```
public static <T> Converter<ResponseBody, T> getConverter(Class<? extends T> type) {
    return sRetrofit.responseBodyConverter(type, new Annotation[0]);
}
```

Then caller can do:

```
Converter<ResponseBody, String> cvt = getConverter(String.class);
```

or in Java 10+:

```
var cvt = getConverter(String.class);
```